# Living world ship short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, generation-ship

I read a short story years ago and would like to find it again. It was about a world ship of mysterious origin traveling for millions of years. There was a group of (presumably) humans living near the engines of the ship. This group was fighting a war against some sort of non-sentient organisms. There was also some sort of coup near the control center, but the book did not go into much detail about that.

That's all I can think of. I would appreciate some help figuring out which story this is. Thanks.

Comment: Can you recall any other details about this?

Comment: I remember that the humans had a guest staying with them who may have been the last of his species.

Comment: Another detail is that no one knows the purpose of the world ship.

Comment: Sounds like one of the "The Ship" stories by Robert Reed; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(novel)

Comment: Sorry. I read the story (not book) about a decade ago. I can't remember if the ship itself is alive. It may be one of the Greatship stories by Robert Reed, as @Valorum pointed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is "[Hatch](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?534205)" by Robert Reed, one of his 'great ship' short stories.

- World ship of mysterious origin traveling for millions of years - **Check**
- Group of (presumably) humans living near the engines of the ship - **Check**
- This group was fighting a war - **Check**
- Against some sort of non-sentient organisms - **Check**
- Some sort of coup - **Check**

> *This particular one is about passengers stranded on the outside of the
> ship's hull and forced to survive there while cut off from the
> increasingly mysterious interior of the vessel. Living in a rocket
> nozzle on the gas giant-sized ship, they live off the remains of an
> alien attacker's body that has formed an ecosystem on the ship's
> exterior. Peregrine, a prosperous "raider" whose job is harvesting the
> periodic "hatches" that send enormous swarms of aliens up into the
> atmosphere of the "Polypond," now in the midst of an affair with an
> old engineer who knew his mother, catches wind of a rare giant
> hatching which, of course, may well lead to much more than that.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Nader Elhefnawy reviews - The New Space Opera Ed. Gardner Dozois](http://www.irosf.com/q/zine/article/10477)</sup></sub>